# Looping through each bootstrap slide

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to loop through the bootstrap carousel and apply some jquery to each slide.

The jquery:

```
$('.carousel-inner .item').each(function() {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  var carouselHeight = $(this).find('#homecarouselheight').outerHeight();
  $(this).find('.carousel-triangle').css('border-width', '45px 0 0 ' + windowWidth + 'px');
  $(this).find('.carousel-triangle').css('bottom', carouselHeight + 'px');
});
```

html:

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="carousel-triangle test" style="border-width: 45px 0px 0px 1322px; bottom: 63px;"></div>v>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="carousel-triangle test" style="border-width: 45px 0px 0px 1322px; bottom: 0px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason this is only applying the the first slide. Any idea how I can apply it to each slide individually since there is dynamic content within.

EDIT - I have added the html as you can see the 63px is being applied to the first slide but no height is getting added to the second.

Comment: Can you post your html code?

Comment: @Sky i have updated the question

Comment: You only have one `.item` element within your `.carousel-inner` element. In the HTML that you provided, you have an extra `</div>`.

Comment: @krillgar my mistake - there is only one div. have removed.

Comment: What's the length of `$('.carousel-inner .item')` you got from your console?

Comment: @Sky when i console.log(carouselHeight); i get 2x 0. so not even getting the 63

Comment: Where's your `homecarouselheight`? Can you get this object? You can try to debug using console to watch the value.

Comment: It works in my local with this line commented: `var carouselHeight = $(this).find('#homecarouselheight').outerHeight();`.